# ¿Cómo saber que valores de una clave en JSON es igual a vacio?

Tags: javascript, json

no se si se entienda mi pregunta. La situación es la siguiente.
Estoy trabajando con JAVASCRIPT y JSON, donde tengo un array JSON como el siguiente:

```
var dientes = {
            "diente1": [
                        { "Tratamientos":[] }
                    ]
        };
```

Y voy agregando tratamientos con push, así como también, los elimino. Y en fin juego con el array JSON.

Poniendo un ejemplo de que agrego 3 tratamientos y posterior elimino esos mismos 3 tratamientos. 
Se que se puede hacer con un length pero, en el array JSON al eliminar con delete, el length no cambia, es decir, cuando agrego los 3 tratamientos, length vale 3, y cuando elimino estos tratamientos, length sigue valiendo 3, a pesar de que elimine los tratamientos, y los espacios tienen un undefined, o eso me aparece si los imprimo, entonces ¿Como saber que "Tratamientos" en el JSON no tiene tratamientos?

Comment: te recomiendo usar el metodo `Object.keys()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomiendo usar el método `Object.keys()`, este retornara el **length** de la matriz de los elementos actualmente definidos (sin incluir los no definidos o eliminados), te dejo un ejemplo de como hacerlo:

```js
var dientes = 
    { "diente1": 
        { "Tratamientos": [
            { "1":"a1" },
            { "2":"a2" }
          ]
        }
      
    };
console.log(dientes.diente1.Tratamientos.length)
console.log(dientes.diente1.Tratamientos)
delete dientes.diente1.Tratamientos["1"]

// obtener el length de los elementos (sin incluir los eliminados)
console.log(Object.keys(dientes.diente1.Tratamientos).length)
console.log(dientes.diente1.Tratamientos)
```

Comment: Gracias, colega, tu respuesta me ayudo y soluciono mi pregunta

Answer (score 3):

Al fin y al cabo, lo que tienes definido es un objeto JavaScript y en concreto, *tratamientos* es un array, por lo que podemos comprobar con `length` cuantos elementos se encuentran en ese array. Si es `0`, el array está vacío.

```
if(dientes.diente1[0].Tratamientos.length == 0)
{
    console.log("Tratamientos de diente1 está vacío");
}
```

Si tuviéramos más dientes definidos en el objeto, podríamos iterar por las propiedades de dientes (ojo, igual te convenía convertirlo a un array en lugar de un objeto) y comprobar los tratamientos de cada uno.

```
for (diente in dientes) {
  console.log('El diente ' + diente + ' tiene ' + dientes[diente][0].Tratamientos.length + ' tratamientos.');
}
```

Comment: lo que dices es correcto con la propiedad `length` podemos conocer el numero de elementos del **arrays** pero cuando eliminas un elemento del **arrays** con `delete`, `length` continua mostrando el mismo numero de elementos (incluyendo el eliminado).

Comment: @fwBasic efectivamente, así es. La última edición del OP invalidó esta respuesta. No obstante, la dejo como consulta.